# Modify ConnectionString on access

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, web-config

I want to adjust the `Application Name` part off all sql connectionstrings before they get first used. We use SqlConnection and DataContext classes for SQL queries, so it needs to work with both.

So is there any possibility to intercept the access to the connection strings for sql database access? So I can modify the `Application Name`.

Comment: I'm curious, in what way do you intend to modify the connection string? When you say "everytime it is accessed" do you mean that every time a query is executed you want a new connection that is different? If so, why?

Comment: I updated my question. we want to set the `Application Name` to the name of the executing server.